# Making a simple HTTP request using ESP01 and AT commands

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to make a simple HTTP request using the esp8266-01 using AT commands, the esp8266-01 is connected to my arduino uno and im typing commands into the serial monitor. The esp is already connected to internet but i cant get the request to work.

I tried making this request:

```
AT+HTTPCLIENT=1,0,"http://httpbin.org/get","httpbin.org","/get",1"
```

which i got from the official espressif documentation but i only get an simple "ERROR". Can anyone help?

Comment: Consider adding relevant code to your question so people here can help you figuring out what might be causing the problem.

Comment: AT+HTTPCLIENT is in AT 2 which is not compatible with esp-01 (requires at least 1 MB flash)

Answer (score 0):

I use `AT+HTTPPARA` to set the URL and then `AT+HTTPACTION=0` to send the request.

Here's an example that I use for [ThingSpeak](https://nothans.com/send-data-to-thingspeak-with-at-commands):

```
"AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&field1=42\"";

"AT+HTTPACTION=0"
```